# Responsive Sidebar Using Transition Takes up more than 100% width and height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on a responsive sidebar that appears when the button to make it appear is clicked on, it uses the transition effect, and does not make the page take up more than 100% width or height of the page. It works great except on smaller screen sizes. It then takes up more than 100% of the page's width and/or height.

```js
    $("#sidebar-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
```

```css
html {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar-toggle-button {
        margin-left: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 100px;
        display: block;
    }

    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        position: fixed;
        left: 250px;
        width: 0;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -250px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: black;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: -250px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <aside id="sidebar-wrapper"></aside>
    <button id="sidebar-toggle" class="sidebar-toggle-button">Toggle</button>
    <div id="page-content-wrapper"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is you are able to scroll right and sometimes even down if the browser window is small for some reason. You are not able to do so using if the screen size is large (which is what I want), but for whatever reason when the screensize is small you can scroll right... even on screensizes on 100%. If content is added to the page, sometimes you are even able to scroll down. I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc(100% - 250px)` in your `#page-content-wrapper` class, once your side has 250px size.

```js
    $("#sidebar-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
```

```css
html {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar-toggle-button {
        margin-left: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 100px;
        display: block;
    }

    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        position: fixed;
        left: 250px;
        width: 0;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -250px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: black;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        height: 100%;
        width: calc(100% - 250px);
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: absolute;
        margin-right: -250px;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <aside id="sidebar-wrapper"></aside>
    <button id="sidebar-toggle" class="sidebar-toggle-button">Toggle</button>
    <div id="page-content-wrapper"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I spent so much time on this! You're the man!

Comment: calc might have issues in some browsers :)

Answer (score 1):

The Only change in your code is :

```
  #page-content-wrapper {
        left: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
    html {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .sidebar-toggle-button {
        margin-left: 15px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2;
        top: 100px;
        display: block;
    }

    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        position: fixed;
        left: 250px;
        width: 0;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: -250px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: black;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        margin-left: -250px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <aside id="sidebar-wrapper"></aside>
        <button id="sidebar-toggle" class="sidebar-toggle-button">Toggle</button>
        <div id="page-content-wrapper"></div>
    </div>

  
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("#sidebar-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: calc might have issues in some browsers.